# Call to _path method undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I have a simple partial:

```
<div class="gallery">
  <a href="#" class="icon-left-arrow"></a>
  <ul>
    <% if products.any? %>
      <% products.each do |product| %>
    <li>
      <%=link_to small_image(product)%>
      <div class="product-info">
        <p class="product-name">Product name</p>
        <p>optional  Brand/ Artist</p>
      </div>
    </li>    
    <% end %>    
  </ul>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to '', taxonomy_preview_path %>
</div>
```

The following Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  #namespace Oklahoma
  match 'account/paymentmethod/:cc_type/:id', to:'user_payment_methods#show', via:[:get], as: 'user_payment_methods'
  #end  
  namespace :api do 
    api_version(module: "V1", header: {name: "Accept", value: "version=1"}, path: {value: "v1"}) do 
      match 'api/search/products/:query.json', to: 'search_api#query', via:[:get], as: 'search_api' 
      match 'api/search/products/prefetch.json', to: 'search_api#prefetch', via:[:get], as: 'search_api_prefetch' 
      #get '/taxonomy_preview', to: 'search#taxonomy_preview', as: 'taxonomy_preview' 
    end
  end
  get '/taxonomy_preview' => 'search#taxonomy_preview', as: 'taxonomy_preview'     
end
```

I get a NoMethodError... This *should* work... Strangely enough when I go into console and do  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers, taxonomy_preview_path is defined. Any thoughts?

**Rake routes output:**

```
taxonomy_preview GET  /taxonomy_preview(.:format)                         search#taxonomy_preview
```

**Error Message:**

```
NameError in Spree::Home#index

Showing /apps/oklahoma/app/views/spree/shared/_product_gallery.html.erb where line #16 raised:

undefined local variable or method `taxonomy_preview_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fefeb96aef0>:0x00000005d77120>

Extracted source (around line #16):

14
15
16
17




  </ul>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to('', taxonomy_preview_path)%>
</div>

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/spree/shared/_products_accordian.html.erb, app/views/spree/home/index.html.erb

Rails.root: /apps/oklahoma
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

/gems/spree/core/app/helpers/spree/base_helper.rb:68:in `method_missing'
app/views/spree/shared/_product_gallery.html.erb:16:in `_0bbe9ea65b02d743f8cf85f8b57a0bed'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
deface (1.0.1) lib/deface/action_view_extensions.rb:41:in `render'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:339:in `render_partial'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:310:in `block in render'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:309:in `render'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:21:in `render'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:32:in `render'
app/views/spree/shared/_products_accordian.html.erb:12:in `_a0e85bceb1da533de21b81d8dfbcf657'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
deface (1.0.1) lib/deface/action_view_extensions.rb:41:in `render'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:339:in `render_partial'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:310:in `block in render'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:309:in `render'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:21:in `render'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:32:in `render'
app/views/spree/home/index.html.erb:2:in `_19f37189c938f2f0bcd8ece0399f522c'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
deface (1.0.1) lib/deface/action_view_extensions.rb:41:in `render'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:303:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:819:in `call'
railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:51:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:819:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/versionist-06cef2103456/lib/versionist/middleware.rb:39:in `_call'
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/versionist-06cef2103456/lib/versionist/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:649:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: what is the full error message you are seeing, please do not leave things out. Often it is the place you assume is the most obvious where your own blind spot has prevented you from seeing the error.

Comment: @JasonFB updated question

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed by referencing main_app.[route name]_path... This probably is related to the fact I have another engine(Spree) mounted at /...